# Do we like the current background on Physics SE?

Tags: discussion

Personally, the graph paper design that is characteristic of many StackExchange sites, and currently is the background for Physics SE, is not pleasing to my eye. In fact, it has made me not feel as much like revisiting other StackExchange sites. I know that this is very subjective (and may stem from some deep-seated resentment of graph paper from school), but I find myself not wanting to visit sites as much that have graph paper or lined paper backgrounds.

I may be alone in preferring the plain background of Stack Overflow and Math Overflow. I'm not saying that this site should have the same site design as those sites, but do we need to have the same background as so many other SE sites? If you personally love the graph paper background, please state why rather than downvoting this question. If you would prefer something else, do you have any suggestions for an alternative background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The graph paper design is used for all beta sites. It's only temporary. If we get promoted to a full SE site, we'll get our own individual design that will be created with community input.

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess I'm just out of luck then about getting it changed. Hopefully it doesn't rub other people wrongly like it does to me.

Comment: No, you're not out of luck, you just have to wait a while. And do your best to make sure the site succeeds so that we will be considered "worthy" of achieving full status ;-)

Comment: Well, I meant out of luck for now. I'll just have to endure it during the beta.

Comment: @Justin: If you feel really strongly about it you could write a grease monkey script to replace it for you on the fly.

Comment: Hah - Feel strongly.

Comment: Or a custom stylesheet might be able to do it. (I think that's possible with certain browsers, not sure which ones though)

Comment: you can use something like [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) or [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) (for firefox) to change the css of the site until then

Comment: @David-- what sort of community input resulted in the white on black background? From the two digit upvotes to all the negative posts about it, it seems that the larger community's input is that it is irritating. If I missed an opportunity for input, apologies.

Comment: @Gordon: that would be [this thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/304) and then [this one](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/447).

Comment: @David--Ok I have looked at those threads and left comments. I don't see much discussion--a few positive comments and quite a few reservations. Much of the discussion seems to centre on the equations on the blackboard, which has really nothing to do with the current black/grey background unless you use some super photo-enhancer technology on it. I can live with it, but it is not easier to read or concentrate using it. Are the books and papers you read all the time printed on black paper? Would you like them to be?

Answer (score 2):

I definately do not like the background it seems too busy for my taste that is why i used this little trick to overlay a plain old solid background.

Internet explorer for windows and Konqueror for Linux support overlaying a solid background in there template area in setting. Just in-case assuming IE Open your Internet Options (either from the Tools menu in Internet Explorer, or from the Control Panel), then click the Colors and Accessibility buttons at the bottom to adjust the default colors.

For any Linux buffs http://www.google.com/url?q=http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-baseapps/konqueror/menubar.html&sa=U&ei=8BevT5WDNsXMtge79-DYCA&ved=0CB0QFjAD&usg=AFQjCNHB4xLlylBUmBXf8-ge7h2VP7yRkg